# Applying date to both %y and %Y

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe where one of the columns called 'date', containing objects, looks like:

df =

```
|Date
|Mar-24
|Aug-22
|Sep-25
|...
```

I want to convert that column into date so for example Mar-24 would look like 2024-03-01. So far i have tried

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format= '%b-%y')
```

which i think should work but from the few thousand rows i've found that there are rows which contain the full year such as 'Apr 2023' which won't be picked up by %y, is there a way i could find those rows in the column and change them into the short year before applying the above code or just giving the code both %y and %Y arguments?

Comment: I never used panda before, will to_datetime raise an Exception if the format is wrong? if yes, then maybe a use try: except: to use the first formating and fallback to the other formating if not applicable

Comment: I just get ValueError: unconverted data remains: ...

Comment: try doing this then https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions, first try with the first format, then inside `except ValueError:` use the second format, that way if the first format fail, it will use the second format.

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter errors='coerce' in combination with combine_first:

Minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(['Mar-24', 'Aug-22', 'Sep-2025'], [0, 1, 2])
date1 = pd.to_datetime(series, format='%b-%y', errors='coerce')
date2 = pd.to_datetime(series, format='%b-%Y', errors='coerce')
date1.combine_first(date2)
```

Output:

```
0   2024-03-01
1   2022-08-01
2   2025-09-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or for your specific case in one line:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%y', errors='coerce').combine_first(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b-%Y', errors='coerce'))
```